# Web3 error handling in React

Tags: web3js, ethereumjs, react

This is really a two part question.

First, the only way I can get the error message thrown by a Smart Contract `require` statement is to call the function first with a `call` rather than a `send`. `send` does not return the message thrown by a failed `require` statement whereas `call` does.

Example. In Solidity I might have the following:

`require (org._isUser(_user),'Error: User not registered');`

In my React frontend I want to be able to display 'Error: User not registered'.

My function call in React is as follows:

```
async function createPO(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    const poeacct = e.target.elements[0].value
    const ponumber = e.target.elements[1].value
    const podate = e.target.elements[2].value
    let callOK = true
    try {
      await contract2.methods
        .createOrder('0xd2c4895e24095f23277df168f94a6c035813fe5d', poeacct, ponumber, podate)
        .call({ from: accounts[0] })
    } catch (err) {
      callOK = false
      setMess(err.message)
      console.log(err)
    }
    if (callOK) {
      await contract2.methods
        .createOrder('0xd2c4895e24095f23277df168f94a6c035813fe5d', poeacct, ponumber, podate)
        .send({ from: accounts[0] })

      setpouAcct(pouacct)
      setpoeAcct(poeacct)
      setpoNumber(ponumber)
      setpoDate(podate)
      setMess('Transaction successful')
    }
  }
```

This works but it's kind of klugey so I'm wondering if there's a better way.

Second. The error returned by the 'catch' in the Web3 call is JSON but there's a prefix:

```
Error: [object Object]
{
  "message": "VM Exception while processing transaction: revert Error: Order already exists",
  "code": -32000,
  "data": {
    "0x270bb8ddea630f3fc42a4f6196d7710cc50779a34994fd534a8ce139976b0ef5": {
      "error": "revert",
      "program_counter": 21219,
      "return": "0x08c379a00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001b4572726f723a204f7264657220616c7265616479206578697374730000000000",
      "reason": "Error: Order already exists"
    }
```

The `Error: [object Object]` prefix prevents me from parsing out the 'reason:' node. If I remove the prefix manually (i.e. hard code it) it works.

I've tried `substring`,`slice` and JSON.parse etc. but I can't find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to JuliSmz answer, but I wasn't comfortable with the magic 56 character string position as I was worried it would be brittle. I wrote this little function which takes the error object returned by the `catch`

```
    function getRPCErrorMessage(err){
        var open = err.stack.indexOf('{')
        var close = err.stack.lastIndexOf('}')
        var j_s = err.stack.substring(open, close + 1);
        var j = JSON.parse(j_s);
        var reason = j.data[Object.keys(j.data)[0]].reason;
        return reason;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the parse part to work like this:

`setMess(JSON.parse(err.message.substring(15).trim()).message)`

Still thinking there must be a cleaner way of handling errors passed from Web3.

Comment: Did you find any better way to parse the error?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, using truffle, I've solved this way:

```
...catch((err) => {
    let message = JSON.parse(err.message.substring(56).trim().replace("'", "")).value.data.data;
    console.log(message[Object.keys(message)[0]].reason);
```

On this way I can show the message I set on my solidity contract.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use estimateGas() for validating transaction
2. You can differentiate errors based on the typeof error, now we can get message of any transaction error

```
async function createPO(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    const poeacct = e.target.elements[0].value
    const ponumber = e.target.elements[1].value
    const podate = e.target.elements[2].value
    let callOK = true
    try {
      const contractCaller = contract2.methods.createOrder('0xd2c4895e24095f23277df168f94a6c035813fe5d', poeacct, ponumber, podate)
      const gas = await contractCaller.estimateGas({ from: accounts[0] })
      const response = await contractCaller.send({ from: accounts[0] })

      setpouAcct(pouacct)
      setpoeAcct(poeacct)
      setpoNumber(ponumber)
      setpoDate(podate)
      setMess('Transaction successful')

    } catch (err) {
        if(error.__proto__.name === "Error"){ 
            const start = error.message.indexOf("{");
            const end = error.message.indexOf("}");
            if(start && end) {
                error = JSON.parse(error.message.substring(start, end + 1));
            }
        }
        setMess(err.message)
        console.log(err)
    }
}
`
```

Answer (score 0):

Pasting my answer from S.O. here. Her's how I did it:

For me, the "require" reason is there in the `message` property of the `error` object, but it is surrounded by lot of other words which I don't need.

An example error message:

```
[ethjs-query] while formatting outputs from RPC '{"value":{"code":-32603,"data":{"message":"VM Exception while processing transaction: revert Voting is closed","code":-32000,"data":{"0xf901429f12096d3b5c23a80e56fd2230fa37411bb1f8d3cdbd5c8f91c2670771":{"error":"revert","program_counter":43,"return":"0x08c379a0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000165f5f5f566f74696e6720697320636c6f7365645f5f5f00000000000000000000","reason":"Voting is closed"},"stack":"RuntimeError: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert Voting is closed \n    at Function.RuntimeError.fromResults (/tmp/.mount_ganachreY1gT/resources/static/node/node_modules/ganache-core/lib/utils/runtimeerror.js:94:13)\n    at BlockchainDouble.processBlock (/tmp/.mount_ganachreY1gT/resources/static/node/node_modules/ganache-core/lib/blockchain_double.js:627:24)\n    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)\n    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)","name":"RuntimeError"}}}}'
```

You can see the reason `Voting is closed` stuck in between. Not that user-friendly to read.
I've seen answers that use regex to extract the error reason.

For those like me, who are not a big fan of the regex way, here is my approach.

1. In your solidity contract, wrap the require reason with a unique delimiter of sorts. In my case, it is "___" (3 underscores).

```
    contract MyContract{
       ...
       ...
       function vote(address _addr) public payable{
          require(votingOpen, "___Voting closed___");
          ...
       }
       ...
       ...
    }
```

2. Declare a helper function to extract the error using JavaScript string utilities. Here's where your delimiter coes in handy.

```
export const extractErrorCode = (str) => {
    const delimiter = '___'; //Replace it with the delimiter you used in the Solidity Contract.
    const firstOccurence = str.indexOf(delimiter);
    if(firstOccurence == -1) {
        return "An error occured";
    }

    const secondOccurence = str.indexOf(delimiter, firstOccurence + 1);
    if(secondOccurence == -1) {
        return "An error occured";
    }

    //Okay so far
    return str.substring(firstOccurence + delimiter.length, secondOccurence);
}
```

3. Use this function where you catch the error in your frontend

```
const vote = async (_addr) => {
        setLoading(true);
        try {
            await contest.methods.vote(_addr).send({
                from: accounts[0],
            })
        }
        catch (e) {
            console.log('Voting failed with error object => ', e)
            console.log('Voting failed with the error => ', extractErrorCode(e.message))
        }
        setLoading(false);
    }
```

Like other answers here, this too is a workaround. However, I prefer this one over others because I am not that great with regex, and additionally, this one does not depend on a fixed starting position to extract the error code.